# Violation of Primary Key Constraint; SQL Server Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, primary-key, sql-server-express

First, I am using SQL Server 2014 Express.

Second, I am using the SQL Server 2014 Import and Export Wizard.

I have imported a few items successfully using this same program. This is the exact error:

> Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred.
>
> Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
>   Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "The statement has been terminated.".
>
> An OLE DB record is available.
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
>   Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_GEOG'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.geog'. The duplicate key value is (00, 06, 000001).".
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

This is coming from a flat file source. I have imported this into excel and access and ran various tests. There is no other row in the database that contains `(00, 06, 000001)` in the first three columns.

These columns make up the primary key (state, type, area). I am no expert but I was not able to find a trigger connected to this table (GEOG).

Comment: Have you check there's no duplicate primary key value in the file?

Comment: There are 12632 rows. As a test, I concatenate the first three columns into one value (0006000001 in this case) and then remove duplicates. Excel says that no duplicates exist. Additionally, in excel when i filter the state column by 00 only 11 rows come up. There are no duplicates in those 11.

Comment: it is not really an answer. However, cracked the code. In the past, when the import would fail, my table (GEOG) would be empty. For some reason, it imported some of it but not all but still gave me the same error. It even said Stopped in the checklist. I went to the table and deleted all rows and re-imported. It seems as if I have a buggy edition.

Comment: To be double sure, copy your PK data from excel to sql server table(copy paste) and run `select col1, count(col1) from table group by col1 having count(col1) >1` . If it returns row, you have duplicates. else 'maybe' buggy edition.